# Update entity on cart page programmatically Drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce, updating

I need to rewrite default view - commerce_cart_form, because of my design of /cart page. So, I've created file views-view--commerce-cart-form.tpl.php and try to repeat something like on original /cart page were. I can print all needed information about line items in cart, but I don't know how to create "Update" button, to change quantity which I typed in textfield with quantity of line item. That's why I want to get help with this.

I use Drupal Commerce 7.x-1.9

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: view - commerce_cart_form is a view. Why don't you edit the view? You can change the output in many ways with Views GUI...

Comment: I need to add some divs on that page. So, it is easier to write my own view template file.

Comment: If I get you right, I need to write in views-view--commerce-cart-form.tpl.php file something like this:
`echo "<div class='title_page_view'>In cart</div>";
$name = "commerce_cart_form";
echo views_embed_view($name, $display_id = 'default');`
Am I right?

Comment: Not a good idea in fact. I posted an answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to display the full view result and add some extra content to your cart, put the following lines in a file named `views-view--commerce-cart-form.tpl.php` :

```
if($view->current_display == 'default'){//OR your display
  //dsm($view);
  print $rows;
  print '<div>MY CUSTOM CONTENT</div>';
}
```

Check [views-view.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!views-view.tpl.php/7) doc to see available variables.

Otherwise, have a look at [Commerce Cart View Override](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_cart_view_override) :

> This module provides the ability to override the default cart page
>   view for Drupal Commerce.

Comment: Thanx a lot!!! That is exactly what I wanted!!